# Cohomology ring of non oriented surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the best way to compute cohomology ring of $A_k=RP^2\sharp RP^2\sharp \cdots \sharp RP^2$ with coefficients in $Z_2$ without appealing to symplical cohomology?

Answer (score 0):

Mayer-Vietoris? $A_k = A_{k-1} \# RP^2 = (A_{k-1} \setminus D^2) \cup_{S^1} (RP^2 \setminus D^2)$.